# JQuery issue with onclick slide up function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have script for slideup and slide down function in jquery, and a button each of them.
 both are working fine until i thought of giving the slide up from by letting the user click anywhere in the site.. i.e., when user clicks slide down button its slides down and when he click anywhere on the screen later the content slides up.

unfortunately its having a small problem of auto sliding down and sliding up when i hit slide down button.

the script as follow::

```
<div id="a" name="a">
    </br>
    <small><p id="date2"><?php echo $row2["date"]; ?></p></small>
    <p><B><big><font color= #ba4a00> A:</font></B></big> <small><?php echo $row2["answer"]; ?></small></p>
</div>

<button id="showmoreless" class="hide">Hide Answers</button>
        <button id="showmoreless" class="show">Show Answers</button>

<script type='text/javascript' src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js">
</script>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".hide").hide();
        $('[name="a"]').slideUp();
        $(".show").click(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            $(this).parent().find('[name="a"]').slideDown();
            $(this).hide();
            $(this).parent().find(".hide").show();
        }); 

        $('[name="a"]').click(function(e){
            e.stopPropagation();
        });

        $(window).click(function(e) {
            console.log($(e.target));
            if (!$(e.target).is('[name="a"]')) {
                $('.show').show();
                $('[name="a"]').slideUp(); 
            }
        });

    });
</script>
```

Any help is Appreciated..

Comment: I think your issue is it is animating continuously when you click quickly... right?

Comment: Where is your element with the class `show`? Also, it would be better if your example did not include your php code.

Comment: yes . when i click slide down, it slide down and up al of a sudden..

Comment: Did you gave it try by using .slideToggle()? instead of slideUp and slideDown

Comment: no..  but it actually worked well when i two buttons each fir slide up and down....

Comment: Holy outdated html batman! `font` `big` `b` !!

Answer (score 0):

It slides back up straight away because both your event handlers are executing - by definition a click on your `show` element is also a click on the window.

To stop this happening you need `stopPropagation`

```js
$(".hide").hide();
$('[name="a"]').slideUp();
$(".show").click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  $(this).parent().find('[name="a"]').slideDown();
  $(this).hide();
  $(this).parent().find(".hide").show();
  e.stopPropagation(); // <-- here
}); 

$('[name="a"]').click(function(e){
  e.stopPropagation();
});

$(window).click(function(e) {
  //console.log($(e.target));
  if (!$(e.target).is('[name="a"]')) {
    $('.show').show();
    $('[name="a"]').slideUp(); 
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="a" name="a">
    <br>
    <small><p id="date2">date here</p></small>
    <p><big><font color= #ba4a00> A:</font></big> <small>answer here</small></p>
</div>

<button id="showmoreless" class="hide">Hide Answers</button>
<button id="showmoreless" class="show">Show Answers</button>
```

Comment: nope... it isn't working... its like freezed when i load the page keeping the slidedown function with no button working..

Comment: @user6779766 - I dont follow. Does this snippet work for you?

Comment: i dont know either... i copied exactl your script but it shows no action..

Comment: And I ask again: Does the snippet work in my answer?

Comment: Then you've got something else in your actual code which youve not included in your question.

Comment: do you have any js conflicts

Comment: why did you commented `console.log($(e.target));` in your script

Comment: It was obscuring the rest of the content once it had been collapsed. Which meant I couldnt test it on second click.